# Use XPath to pull text from a string

Tags: xml, xpath, metadata

From the XML below, how would I retrieve the values
`Tarboro, NC`, `Coward` and `Charndra` with XPath

```
<calldata>
    <group>/LOCAL CONSUMER SOLUTIONS/Consumer QA/Retention/Tarboro,      NC/CSC_RET_TRBO Coward, Charndra/</group>
<calldata>
```

Comment: <calldata> <group>/LOCAL CONSUMER SOLUTIONS/Consumer QA/Retention/Tarboro, NC/CSC_RET_TRBO Coward, Charndra/</group> <calldata>

Comment: update your question, don't add it as comment

Comment: above is the xml, the site posted it differently than it was typed

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed (as mentioned in the answer below). You end-tag should be `</calldata>`.

Comment: What is your coding attempt?

Answer (score 1):

Your XPATh is:

```
/calldata/group
```

btw. the XML you provided is not well formed.

With XPATH you can only set the Path to an element / a collection of elements. Within the Element you have to extract the data with another function like "split" in your programming language.

Comment: i am very green when it comes to xpath, would you mind pointing me to a link that would explain how to use the split function? @Time084

Comment: First i need to know which programming language you use. Tell us a little bit more about your project